# can't get orcc code to run using C backend with visual studio 2010

Tags: c, eclipse, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors, cmake

So I've created an ORCC project on eclipse and I've compiled my main network successfully and I generated the visual studio 2010 solution using CMake.

**But** when I try to run my generated solution i get a lot of compilation errors of undeclared identifiers and unrecognized methods.

I thought the whole point of the back end generated by eclipse is that it should run out of the box without the need for me to edit anything.

**Any Help** is appreciated, thank you.

here is a sample of the errors, if you want me to attach the whole error list, let me know.

- Error    295 error C2039: 'read_inds' : is not a member of 'fifo_i16_s'
  397  1   network
- Error    297 error C2039: 'read_inds' : is not a member of 'fifo_i16_s'
  558  1   network
- Error    71  error C2065: 'cpu_set_t' : undeclared identifier
  222  1   network
- Error    73  error C2065: 'cpuset' : undeclared identifier 222   1   network
- Error    104 error C2065: 'cpuset' : undeclared identifier 237   1   network
- Error    121 error C2065: 'cpuset' : undeclared identifier 242   1   network
- Error    85  error C2065: 'mapping' : undeclared identifier 232  1   network

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try with a more recent version of Orcc, they have improved the code generator, which now exports everything that is needed (including libraries and headers).

If it does not work, you can also send an email to the Orcc mailing list or contact them on IRC directly (details on the project's homepage http://orcc.sourceforge.net/).